# Best way to setup a page with a form (questionnaire) on Magento 1.9.1?

Tags: magento-1.9, forms

```
Magento 1.9.1
Porto theme
```

I need to setup a kind of "Create your own custom basket" page where I ask the customers a few questions about what they would like in their baskets, how many etc. and then Email them an estimate.

What is the best way to do this in Magento 1.9.1?

Would a simple HTML form work? Is there a Send.php program inside Magento? I have the Porto theme and it has a contact page which gets sent by Email (it has sort of form fields) but I cannot figure out how that works?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension for product inquiry and quotes:

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-inquiry-1-1.html